# Check value of all cells in datagridview for null in c#

Tags: c#

i want to check and set the value of all those cells in datagridview which have null values
like

```
firstname          lastname     DOB
AAA                             12/12/1212
BB                  CC
                    DD          12/12/1212
```

now output should be

```
 firstname          lastname     DOB
    AAA                null      12/12/1212
    BB                  CC       null
    null                DD       12/12/1212
```

Comment: you can do it in query where  using case or in c# code behind use itemdatabound event and check all the value and replace

Comment: is this what you're  looking for? [`DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue.aspx#Y0)